# How to get/create HTML id in MaxButtons Plugin for WordPress for use in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using MaxButtons in WordPress to create stylish buttons which has worked quite well so far.  I would however like to apply my own javascript/jQuery to individual buttons when pressed in order to do things more advanced than just go to a new page - like set values in localStorage, etc.

What I can't seem to locate or create is the HTML id for the button for use within javascript/jQuery to carry out this logic.  I have used 'inspect element' on the webpage but it does not show a HTML id.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get/create a HTML id from individual buttons in MaxButtons for use in scripting?

Example button HTML:

```
<a class="maxbutton-11 maxbutton maxbutton-toolkit-profiler ProfileTempC" title="Profiler" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="ProfileTemp">
    <span class="mb-text">Profiler</span>
</a>
```

Example jQuery:

```
jQuery('#.maxbutton-11').click( function() {

    localStorage.removeItem('GoalType');

    if (confirm('Would you like initial options based on templates?\n\n   Select OK to use templates\n\n   Select Cancel to start from scratch')) {
       window.location = "../template_select.html";
    } else {
       window.location = "../wp431.html";
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need an `id`. You can use a selector like `#buttons button:nth-child(3)` Add the HTML of the button (including surrounding elements) to your question and we can provide more concrete help.

Comment: Hi - when I inspect the element of the button I get the following: <a class="maxbutton-11 maxbutton maxbutton-toolkit-profiler ProfileTempC" title="Profiler" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="ProfileTemp"><span class="mb-text">Profiler</span></a>

Comment: The 11 in there looks like it's probably unique to the button? In that case you can use that to grab it: `jQuery('.maxbutton-11').click(...);`

Comment: Yes - the 11 is unique to the button.  I tried your approach which makes sense (also with some variants in name) however no luck.  I wonder if the javascript:void(0); hinders things - I don't think I can change it in any case..Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The `href` only comes into play when the assigned click handler(s) don't cancel the MouseEvent. Add the code you have tried to the question.